# strange error dotnetopenauth when denying access to a third party app

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth, oauth-2.0

I've been working on developing a OAuth2 provider for quite a bit and I'm using DotNetOpenAuth, and I thought I had everything working, but I forgot to see what would happen if I deny access to a third party app. Well, it seems there's is something malfunctioning with the library, since it throws an error which I don't understand.

I based my developing on the dotnetopenauth ctp samples, theres is a oauth provider implementation, and tried to deny access to an app on the sample and the same thing happens.

The error is: The following required parameters were missing from the DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Messages.EndUserAuthorizationFailedResponse message: error

The stack trace: http://pastebin.com/U95NTVxe.

So:

- the app request for authorization
- then I log on the user who needs to grant authorization
- then the auth server asks the user if he's willing to grant the app access to his resources
- when the user clicks no, this error happens

Thnak you un advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error handling in the OAuth 2 spec has not been very stable (the spec itself is unfinished).  So the DotNetOpenAuth OAuth 2.0 CTPs do not have error handling (or denial of authorization) fully implemented.  When the spec is finalized, you can expect this scenario to be finished.

Comment: Any improvement on denial scenarios ? I try to get the error message set on the Authorization Server ( after calling PrepareRejectAuthorizationRequest) on the relying party. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I had to handle the same problem. I fixed it by converting IDirectProtocolMessage to EndUserAuthorizationFailedResponse, then set the error by myself and pass this object response to PrepareResponse().

```
public ActionResult AuthorizeResponse(bool isApproved)
    {
        var pendingRequest = this.authorizationServer.ReadAuthorizationRequest();

        IDirectedProtocolMessage response;
        if (isApproved)
        {
            //TODO Save authorization here
            response = this.authorizationServer.PrepareApproveAuthorizationRequest(pendingRequest, SessionManager.SsoUser.Username);
        }
        else
        {
            response = this.authorizationServer.PrepareRejectAuthorizationRequest(pendingRequest);

            // Here I set the error by myself
            var errorResponse = response as EndUserAuthorizationFailedResponse;
            errorResponse.Error = "access_denied";
            errorResponse.ErrorDescription = "User rejected the authorization.";

            // And return errorResponse instead of simple response
            return this.authorizationServer.Channel.PrepareResponse(errorResponse).AsActionResult();
        }
        return this.authorizationServer.Channel.PrepareResponse(response).AsActionResult();
    }
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: how to process it from the Client side? I did as you suggested from Authorization Server side but when I call "var authorization = client.ProcessUserAuthorization();" from Client site it returns not null object that doesn't contain any information about error message...

Comment: client.ProcessUserAuthorization() is used when obtaining authorization code (on Token endpoint). It means that this error is handled in Client.RequestUserAuthorization(scopes, returnUrl). In Token endpoint I just surrounded server.HandleTokenRequest() with try catch block and if exception is thrown, I return Json serialized object like { error:"error code, usualy 500", errorDescription="error description with exception message"}.